# Bash: how do i peek and save the first line of stdin

Tags: bash

I have a set files that when cat'ed together have the format

```
NAME1.1 NAME2.1 NAME3.1 KEY1 VALUE1.1 KEY2 VALUE2.1
NAME1.2 NAME2.2 NAME3.2 KEY1 VALUE1.2 KEY2 VALUE2.2
...
NAME1.N NAME2.N NAME3.N KEY1 VALUE1.N KEY2 VALUE2.N
```

and reading through the key value pair text is quote tedious so I thought a processing script is in order so I wrote this

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$@" \
    | head -n1 \
    | awk '{printf("NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 ");for(i=4;i<NF;i+=2){printf("%s ",$i)}printf("\n")}'

cat "$@" \
    |awk '{printf("%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3);for(i=5;i<=NF;i+=2){printf("%s ",$i)}printf("\n")}'
```

As you can see I am playing the files twice just to grab the header row so I can get the values and format them as

```
NAME1   NAME2   NAME3   KEY1     KEY2
NAME1.1 NAME2.1 NAME3.1 VALUE1.1 VALUE2.1
NAME1.2 NAME2.2 NAME3.2 VALUE1.2 VALUE2.2
...
NAME1.N NAME2.N NAME3.N VALUE1.N VALUE2.N
```

Is there a good way to peek and copy the first line so I can save it?

I've tried a one liner like this

```
( cat *.all_my_files \
  | tee >( head -n1 | awk '{printf("NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 ");for(i=4;i<NF;i+=2){printf("%s ",$i)}printf("\n")}' ) \
  | awk '{printf("%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3);for(i=5;i<=NF;i+=2){printf("%s ",$i)}printf("\n")}' \
  ) | column -t
```

but this seems to exit when either of the stdouts finish giving me an indeterminate amount of output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could just pass all the files to awk at once and do something special for the first record:

```
awk 'NR==1{printf("NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 ");for(i=4;i<NF;i+=2){printf("%s ",$i)}print ""}
     {printf("%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3);for(i=5;i<=NF;i+=2){printf("%s ",$i)}' "$@"
```

The first block will be executed only when `NR==1`, which is only true for the first record of the first file. The other block will be executed for all records, including the first one.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I ended up wanting to call a different program than awk.

It's a hack, and it doesn't seem efficient or portable, but if you want to do this strictly in your shell, you can use `read` to grab the first line, and then use a subshell to combine the first line with the rest of stdin before piping it to another command.

```
read -r FIRST_LINE
COL_COUNT="$(echo "$FIRST_LINE" | awk '{print NF; exit}')"

if [[ "$COL_COUNT" -eq "1" ]]; then
  # Do one column things
else
  # Do multi column column things
fi

(echo "$FIRST_LINE" && cat -) | callYourCommand
```